# Rails: how to permit special characters in sanitize helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

the topic question speaks quite for itself - is there a way to instruct `sanitize` helper to leave special characters like `&nbsp;`, `&amp;`, `&lt;`, etc. in the text except to writing custom Scrubber?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?